# How to get distinct count of a column with respective to distinct values of another column in same table?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have marks table with student id, class, section, subject id, total marks and isPassed status (1=pass, 0=fail). 
I want total number of student in a class or section having isPassed status 1 in all subjects.
My query looks like this:

```
 $pass = Marks::select('student_id')
                    ->where('class_room_id', '=', 10)
                    ->where('section_id', '=', 1)
                    ->where('isPassed', '=', 1)
                    ->distinct()
                    ->get();
 $passed = count($pass);
```

The Table looks like:

```
student_id  subject_id  isPassed
  1001           100           1
  1001           101           0
  1001           102           1
  1001           103           1
  1001           104           1

  1002           100           1
  1002           101           1
  1002           102           1
  1002           103           1
  1002           104           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query should be like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(student_id)
FROM marks
WHERE class_room_id = 10
AND student_id NOT IN (SELECT student_id FROM marks WHERE class_room_id = 10 AND isPassed = 0)
```

A nested query `SELECT student_id FROM marks WHERE class_room_id = 10 AND isPassed = 0` selects all students in a given class who have at least one test with `isPassed = 0`. These are the students you DO NOT need.

**UPDATE**

Okay, after having all the information you've provided in the comments, here is the answer.

The query you're looking for is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT student_id)
FROM tbl2
WHERE student_id NOT IN (SELECT student_id FROM tbl2 WHERE isPassed = 0)
```

It gets the number of students who passed all the subjects.

The nested query is:

```
SELECT student_id FROM tbl2 WHERE isPassed = 0
```

It gets the students who failed at least once.

An SQLFiddle to demonstrate it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6baf4/1

Comment: A class has 8 distinct subjects so for each student there are 8 records (isPassed)
Your code returns count based on all students not based on subjects .

Comment: It's not clear from your question. Please update it with the data structure so we can see it.

Comment: please check i have updated the question with table structure.

Comment: So, in your example, student #1002 should be selected, and student #1001 should NOT be selected. Correct?

Comment: No. I want to know total student passed in a class/section. To be pass a student must have isPassed status 1 in all subjects.
I need this : Class 10 => passed= 20

Comment: So which answer is correct for the example data you provided?

Comment: None. Both these answer return same results. Not the appropriate answer that I need.

Comment: I mean, for the data example you have in the question, what should be the correct number of students?

Comment: In above example 1 is passed (i.e. 1002) and 1 is failed (1.e. 1001). because first student is failed on subject 101.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate functions to get a count per group

```
Marks::where('section_id', '=', 1)
    ->where('isPassed', '=', 1)
    ->groupBy('class_room_id')
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(1) as studentCount')
    ->get();
```

This query will return a row per `class_room_id` with a value `studentCount`. If you want only one or a few class rooms, you can add where filters to the query.

Comment: This query does not return based on subjects. Please check i have updated the question with table structure.